# Google Maps choose zoom to fit country TIGHTLY in given window

Tags: google-maps

I am just starting out with the Google Maps API. I have successfully managed to create a map centered on a given country

```
function create_map (geometry) {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: geometry.position,
        zoom: 6 // unimportant, see fitBounds
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map (
        document .getElementById ("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    map.fitBounds (geometry.viewport);
}

function initialize ()
{
    new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode (
        {'address': 'france'},
        function (results, status)
    {
        if (google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK == status)
            create_map (results [0].geometry);
        else
            alert ("bad: "+ status);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener (window, 'load', initialize);
```

This works but the zoom level is chosen with lots of room to spare. I want the map to be as big as possible, with no "comfortable" margin. How can I make the API fit the map tightly to the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. The zoom of a map may only be set to integer-values, but what you're trying to achieve would require a float-value.

Go to http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3Dfrance

The blue rectangle marks the viewport, when you increase the zoom by 1 the blue rectangle will not fit into the container.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong object property. `geometry.position` is `undefined`. You have to use `geometry.location` and you will get better map without `map.fitBounds()`